# BeautifulSoup, Python: parsing lots of element in a lot of div?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a webpage that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45jL9.png) with BeautifulSoup
i have to take the text that i have circled **from each** **div** tag with the **class "quote mediumText"**

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the red circled text in your link try this:

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

source = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/fear").text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
# Remove script tags.
[s.extract() for s in soup('script')]
divs = soup.findAll("div",{'class':'quoteText'})
for div in divs:
    print (div.text.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', ''))
```

Updated to remove script tags line breaks and carriage returns,

Comment: i have done as u have done but the problem is that doing it u take not olso the text but olso the other things in the div

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: i don't know why it takes olso the data inside the script tag:

Comment: //<![CDATA[
      var newTip = new Tip($('quote_book_link_865'), "\n\n  <h2><a class=\"readable bookTitle\" href=\"

Comment: Updated answer to remove script tags line breaks and carriage returns,

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension syntax to do this task in one line:

```
myList = [elem.text for elem in soup.findAll("div",{'class':'quoteText'})]
```

Comment: instead of elem.text and elem i have to put the div **quoteText**?

Comment: No, try executing this exact line. It will extract the `.text` of every `elem` that is inside the `.findAll` return list.

Comment: It shouldn't, in the image the text circled has `class = "quoteText"`, however you mention you want the texts with `class = "quote mediumText"`

Comment: oh, I see, I misunderstood you, using `class: "quoteText"` should do it then. Similar to what Dan-Dev answered above :)

Comment: No worries! No need to apologise

Comment: i done it before u edited it but he givs me olso code and not only text, it is normal?

Comment: If you are using elem.text it should give you text you might get line breaks \n\n etc which you can remove.